# Checking Palindrome numbers function recursively in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion

I don't how to get it work  recursively.
I'm trying to code the Palindrome function recursively. I understand what should i do like that:

```
1       => single digit, therefore yes
--------
12      => 1 != 2, therefore no
--------
121     => 1 == 1, therefore yes
 2      => single digit, therefore yes
--------
1234421 => 1 == 1, therefore yes
 23442  => 2 == 2, therefore yes
  344   => 3 != 4, therefore no
```

However, i got a question. It doesn't work recursively. I need help.
Do i miss something?

```
// Check if a positive integer is a Palindrome
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int number, int factor);

int main()
{
    int number; // a positive integer
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;

    // puts 10^(numDigits-1) (i.e., the smallest numDigits-digit positive integer) into factor
    int temp = number;
    int factor = 1; // power of ten
    while (temp > 9)
    {
        temp /= 10;
        factor *= 10;
    }

    // print whether the number is a palindrome
    if (isPalindrome(number, factor))
        cout << endl << number << " is a palindrome." << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << number << " is not a palindrome." << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}

bool isPalindrome(int number, int factor){
    int checkFirst, checkSecond, temp;

    if (number / 10 > 0){
        checkFirst = number / factor;
        checkSecond = number % 10;
        if (checkFirst == checkSecond){
            temp = number%factor;
            number = temp;
            isPalindrome(number / 10, factor / 10);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

The return value of `isPalindrome()` is not used when called recursively. Add it as a `return` statement.

```
return isPalindrome(number / 10, factor / 10);
```

Also the factor reduces by 100 every time you check two digits. So divide `factor` by `100`.

```
return isPalindrome(number / 10, factor / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!!

```
// Check if a positive integer is a Palindrome
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int number, int factor);

int main()
{
    int number; // a positive integer
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;

    // puts 10^(numDigits-1) (i.e., the smallest numDigits-digit positive integer) into factor
    int temp = number;
    int factor = 1; // power of ten
    while (temp > 9)
    {
        temp /= 10;
        factor *= 10;
    }

    // print whether the number is a palindrome
    if (isPalindrome(number, factor))
        cout << endl << number << " is a palindrome." << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << number << " is not a palindrome." << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}
bool isPalindrome(int number, int factor){
    int checkFirst, checkSecond, temp;
    if (number / 10 > 0){
        checkFirst = number / factor;
        checkSecond = number % 10;
        if (checkFirst == checkSecond){
            temp = number%factor;
            number = temp;
            return isPalindrome(number / 10, factor / 100);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```